# Concatenate arrays into a single table using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a .csv file, from this file I group it by year so that it gives me as a result the maximum, minimum and average values

```
 import pandas as pd
 DF = pd.read_csv("PJME_hourly.csv")

 for i in range(2002,2019):    
     neblina = DF[DF.Datetime.str.contains(str(i))]
     dateframe = neblina.agg({"PJME_MW" : ['max','min','mean']})
     print(i , pd.concat([dateframe],axis=0,sort= False))
```

His output is as follows:

```
 2002            PJME_MW
 max   55934.000000
 min   19247.000000
 mean  31565.617106
 2003            PJME_MW
 max   53737.000000
 min   19414.000000
 mean  31698.758621
 2004            PJME_MW
 max   51962.000000
 min   19543.000000
 mean  32270.434867
```

I would like to know how I can make it all join in a single column (PJME_MW), but that each group of operations (max, min, mean) is identified by the year that corresponds to it.

Comment: you really shouldn't be doing things this way. Almost certainly, you want to use `DF.groupby`

Comment: How can I do so that the maximum, minimum and average values of the same are calculated in a group for each year and everything appears in a single table, since the way I did it gives me the result I want but it generates a different table for each year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert the dates [**`to_datetime()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), you can group them using the [**`dt.year`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) accessor:

```
df = pd.read_csv('PJME_hourly.csv')
df.Datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.Datetime)
df.groupby(df.Datetime.dt.year).agg(['min', 'max', 'mean'])
```

Toy example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Datetime': ['2019-01-01','2019-02-01','2020-01-01','2020-02-01','2021-01-01'], 'PJME_MV': [3,5,30,50,100]})

#      Datetime  PJME_MV
# 0  2019-01-01        3
# 1  2019-02-01        5
# 2  2020-01-01       30
# 3  2020-02-01       50
# 4  2021-01-01      100
```

```
df.Datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.Datetime)
df.groupby(df.Datetime.dt.year).agg(['min', 'max', 'mean'])

#          PJME_MV          
#              min  max mean
# Datetime                  
# 2019           3    5    4
# 2020          30   50   40
# 2021         100  100  100
```

Answer (score 0):

The code could be optimized but how is now works, change this part of your code:

```
    for i in range(2002,2019):    
         neblina = DF[DF.Datetime.str.contains(str(i))]
         dateframe = neblina.agg({"PJME_MW" : ['max','min','mean']})
         print(i , pd.concat([dateframe],axis=0,sort= False))
```

Use this instead

```
aggs = ['max','min','mean']
df_group = df.groupby('Datetime')['PJME_MW'].agg(aggs).reset_index()
out_columns = ['agg_year', 'PJME_MW']
out = []
aux = pd.DataFrame(columns=out_columns)
for agg in aggs:
    aux['agg_year'] = agg + '_' + df_group['Datetime']
    aux['PJME_MW']  = df_group[agg]
    out.append(aux)
df_out = pd.concat(out)
```

**Edit:** Concatenation form has been changed

**Final edit:** I didn't understand the whole problem, sorry. You don't need the code after `groupby` function

Comment: Concatenating like this in a loop is an anti-pattern