# Merging of csv rows using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Afix8.png

Is there a way to merge the rows according to the year to get the mean temp for the year using pandas?

Comment: convert those dates `to_datetime()` and group by `df['month'].dt.year`. very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68062198/13138364

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) function.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Replace here with your full data.
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'month': ["1982-01", "1982-02", "1982-03", "1983-01", "1983-02", "1983-03"],
    'mean_temp': [25.9, 27.1, 27.2, 27, 28, 28.4]
})

print(data)

     month  mean_temp
0  1982-01       25.9
1  1982-02       27.1
2  1982-03       27.2
3  1983-01       27.0
4  1983-02       28.0
5  1983-03       28.4

# Here, we create another column to hold `year`.
data['year'] = pd.to_datetime(data['month']).dt.year
print(data)

     month  mean_temp  year
0  1982-01       25.9  1982
1  1982-02       27.1  1982
2  1982-03       27.2  1982
3  1983-01       27.0  1983
4  1983-02       28.0  1983
5  1983-03       28.4  1983

# Your final dataframe.
aggregated_data = data.groupby(by=['year']).mean()
print(aggregated_data)

      mean_temp
year           
1982  26.733333
1983  27.800000
```